# Create INDEX with relational index options using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have an index like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_MyIndex]
ON [dbo].[TableWithData]([ColumnToAddIndex])
WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON) 
ON [PRIMARY]
```

And with this code, I can create the index due to `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF` are the defaults values

```
entity.HasIndex(e => e.ColumnToAddIndex)
      .HasName("CIX_MyIndex")
      .IsCreatedOnline();
```

But if I want to change these values to ON, I don't find any way to do that, is it possible to use Entity Framework Core to configure indexes like Transact SQL and use any of the relational index options documented in this link?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

I tried to use the `HasAnnotation` method, but I don't know how to configure the string that is required.

```
entity.HasIndex(e => e.ColumnToAddIndex)
      .HasName("CIX_MyIndex")
      .HasAnnoation("STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE", true)
      .IsCreatedOnline();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like .HasFilter doesn't work, In which case it doesn't seem possible to use EF core to configure this, EF core provides a limited set of options for configuring indexes when compared to the options available in TSQL.

I think the only option is to use the RawSQL

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_MyIndex] ON [dbo].[TableWithData]([ColumnToAddIndex]) WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = ON) ON [PRIMARY]");
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations#index-filter

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, the instruction generated in the migration is not a valid SQL: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [CIX_MyIndex] ON [TableWithData] ([ColumnToAddIndex]) WHERE DROP_EXISTING = ON WITH (ONLINE = ON);

Comment: Ok looks like hasfilter is no and there are no more options left except for rawsql @dcanamares

Comment: Probably you are right and the only option is to use the RawSQL, but I would rather use the fluent API of EF.